# Python Squares Function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a function that will return a list of square numbers but will return an empty list if the function takes the parameter ('apple') or (range(10)) or a list. I have the first part done but can't figure out how to return the empty set if the parameter n is not an integer- I keep getting an error: unorderable types: str() > int()
I understand that a string can't be compared to an integer but I need it to return the empty list.

```
def square(n):

    return n**2

def Squares(n):

    if n>0:
        mapResult=map(square,range(1,n+1))
        squareList=(list(mapResult))   
    else:
        squareList=[]

    return squareList
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: My guess is you want a `try...except` block.

Comment: You don't need to use `map`, and you don't need to define a helper function `square`. Use a list comprehension: `[nn**2 for nn in n]`

Comment: ...or else if you insist on not using a list comprehension `map(lambda x: x**2, ...)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `type` function in python to check for what data type a variable is. To do this you would use `type(n) is int` to check if `n` is the data type you want. Also, `map` already returns a list so there is no need for the cast. Therefore...

```
def Squares(n):
    squareList = []

    if type(n) is int and n > 0:
        squareList = map(square, range(1, n+1))

    return squareList
```

Comment: `isinstance` is better. It handles inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

You can chain all the conditions which result in returning an empty list into one conditional using `or`'s. i.e if it is a list, or equals `'apple'`, or equals `range(10)` or `n < 0` then return an empty list. ELSE return the mapResult.

```
def square(n):
    return n**2

def squares(n):
   if isinstance(n,list) or n == 'apple' or n == range(10) or n < 0:
      return []
   else:
      return list(map(square,range(1,n+1)))
```

`isinstance` checks if `n` is an instance of `list`.

Some test cases:

```
print squares([1,2])
print squares('apple')
print squares(range(10))
print squares(0)
print squares(5)
```

Gets

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
>>>
```

Comment: Do Python 3 ranges support equality?

Comment: from some experimentation is seems like they do:
`>>> range(1,10) == range(1,10)
True
>>> range(1,10) == range(1,9)
False`. However reading http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2008-April/013000.html it seems they might not?

Answer (score 0):

You can not compare strings to integers as you have tried to do. If you want to check if `n` is an integer or not, you can use `isinstance()`:

```
def squares(n):
    squareList = []
    if isinstance(n, (int, float)) and n > 0: # If n is an integer or a float
        squareList = list(map(square,range(1,n+1)))     
    return squareList
```

Now, if a string or a list is given as an argument, the function will immediately return an empty list `[]`. If not, then it will continue to run normally.

---

Some examples:

```
print(squares('apple'))
print(squares(5))
print(squares(range(10)))
```

Will return:

```
[]
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
[]
```