# Producing a list of squares from 1 to n

Tags: python

Write a function called squares that takes in a parameter named n. If n is a positive integer, the function returns a list consisting of the squares of the numbers from 1 through n. Otherwise (i.e., if n is not a positive integer) the function should return an empty list.

This function to work correctly even if the function is called with nonsensical arguments. In other words, function calls such as squares('Iowa'), squares(range(10)), and squares([1, 2, 3]) should return an empty list.

def sqrt(x):
    ans = 0
    if x >= 0:
        while ans*ans < x:
            ans+=1
        if ans *ans == x:return ans;

```
return -1;
```

def square(n):
    i=0
    blist= []
    ans = list(range(1, n ))

```
if (n < 0):
    return blist
if isinstance(ans, str):
    return blist
while( i  < len(ans)):
    if(sqrt(ans[i])!= -1):
        blist.append(ans[i])
    i = i+1
return blist
```

i = square('boy')
print(i)

Comment: Try it and post specific problems, instead of asking us to write the code.

Comment: This exact question was asked yesterday.

Comment: @Blender I actually remember that...

Comment: Ouch. Also, the question title didn't seem to match the pasted problem description.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499268/python-squares-function/17499285

Answer (score 4):

To define a function, you do

```
def squares(n): # Where n is the parameter/argument
```

To check if n is an integer or a string (like `Iowa`) or a list (like `range(10)`), use [`isinstance`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) (Hint: the function returns True or False). Use an `if/else` statement here to determine the function either returns an empty list `[]` or to continue:

Use another `if/else` statement to determine whether a number is positive or negative (if it's bigger than 0 it's positive, *else* it's negative)

To get the squares of a number, well, how would you figure out what two squared is? Or three squared? 
`**`

You can then use a list comprehension to get the squares of every number between one and n (but how would you get a list of numbers between one and n? You'll need a *range* or something)

Don't forget to `return` the items ;)

Comment: Good help without writing the code :)

Comment: ok i figure out most of it but i dont know how to use the isinstance i am reading about it thank you for the help

Comment: @user2559235 It works like this: `isinstance(object, type)`. Let's say I do `isinstance('hello', str)`. `hello` is a string (`str` is string), so this returns True. If it was `isinstance('hello', int)`, it would be False because `hello` is a string and not an integer.